# Configuration Store is Disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, identityserver4

ConfigurationDbContext is disposed before the token is generated. When using IdentityServerTools.  I've tried this both with manually adding the ConfigurationDbContext and with relying on the configuration from the Configuration store

in my Startup.cs I've configured IdentityServer like so:

```
//I've also tried without this line
services.AddDbContext<ConfigurationDbContext>(options 
    => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
services.AddIdentityServer()
   .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
   .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
   .AddOperationalStore(options =>
   {
       options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
           builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
            s => s.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

        // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
        options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
        options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
   })
   .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
   {
      options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
         builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
          s => s.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

   });
```

I'm trying to generate a token to consume identityserver as a client from my api.  Sometimes the ConfigurationDbContext is already disposed, sometimes it throws on the first line sometimes it throws on the last

```
private async Task<string> CreatePaymentsTokenAsync()
{
    // Get client for JWT
    var idpClient = await this._configurationDbContext.Clients.Include(x => x.AllowedScopes)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ClientId == Config.APIServerClientId);
    // Get scopes to set in JWT
    var scopes = idpClient.AllowedScopes.Select(s => s.Scope).ToArray();
    // Use in-built Identity Server tools to issue JWT
    var token = await _identityServerTools.IssueClientJwtAsync(idpClient.ClientId, 
        idpClient.AccessTokenLifetime, scopes, new[] { "MyApi" });
    return token;
}
```

This code occasionally works but most of the time it throws an error that the context is disposed, Any idea's on why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend not using the underlying DbContext and favour using IClientStore instead.

As for this problem - how is the class that owns `_configurationDbContext` scoped in the IoC container? It feels like it may have a longer lifetime than the DbContext and thus ends up trying to access a disposed instance.

It also could be because you're forgetting to await somewhere and it causing you're code to fire and forget

```
await CreatePaymentsTokenAsync()
```

Comment: this is in an MVC Controller directly the scope should be transient

Comment: Aha, yes, a lack of await on an awaitable method inside an async method is probably something the compiler should stop.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the CreatePaymentsTokenAsync() awaited from and is that method declared async?

Comment: yeah, it's async

Comment: How is the class containing the CreatePaymentsTokenAsync method registered in your DI container?

Comment: that method is inside of a controller